# Bulk edit products by category

Tags: magento-1.9, category, attributes

I have currently grouped my different brands by categories with the name of the brand. I would now like to use an attribute to control the brand also.

Because of that, I need to bulk edit all products of the category BRAND1 to have the brand-attribute set to BRAND1. I suppose I could use a script to do this, but I would prefer doing it from the Catalog -> Products in backend. Is it possible to sort by category here somehow?

Comment: edit product is a vague term. What part of the product you want to bulk update?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough. I would like to bulk edit a custom attribute called brand - it's a dropdown with multiple values.

Comment: If you prefer not to do that via script, you can try export and then import with you updated attribute. Export sheet will have category column as well.